# Which is really a object?

Tags: java, class, object, instantiation

So I have a problem trying to figure out if some `Object` is really created or it's just some kind of pointer.

Can someone help me understand that please?
I have this kind of example if it helps :)

```
Bookshelf a = new Bookshelf(2);

Bookshelf b = a;

Bookshelf c = b.clone();

Bookshelf []v ={ a,b,c.clone};
```

Comment: And what do you think is the answer and why? Start by making the code compile.

Comment: a, b and c are references to objects (not the objects themselves). a and b reference the same object. c references an object that should be a copy of the object referenced by a and b.

Comment: I really think is a and c, because b is the same as a and is not instantiated with the new operator and the method clone() returns a new object. But the one that I don't really know is the vector v....

Comment: clone() *should* return a new object, but depending on the implementation it might return the same instance or throw an exception instead. Always check if the class implements `Cloneable`.

Comment: Yes it implements :)
And can throw an exception too. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`a` and `b` are the same instance, `c` *should* be an identical `Bookshelf`, but a different instance. `v`, then, contains two unique objects, one of which is in there twice under different names.

Comment: So only a and c are unique objects ( Just to check if i understood it right )

Comment: Yes, although `v` is too.

Comment: @ClaudiaMendes no. They're **references** to objects. `a` and `b` are 2 references to the same object. `c` is a reference to another object, which is a copy (assuming `clone()` does indeed return a copy) of the object referenced by `a` and `b`. `v` is also a reference to an object (the array).

Comment: Well that's what I meant. Note that you can't have the object itself in the code as in C(++), you're always dealing with references.